# Applications in C:\Program Files moved to folder 卓剏㽴褒蚰

Tags: windows-10

I have a windows 10 installation where all of the applications under C:\Program Files were moved to a folder named 卓剏㽴褒蚰 .  The folder appears to have been created a week or so ago, and is owned by TrustedInstaller.
The windows registry key   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx
shows that the program folder location has not changed from c:\Program Files. Windows defender is up to date and did not catch any virus or suspicious activity.  Has anyone seen this behaviour before from a virus or application install?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but I can tell you that although these look like CJK characters (well, they are, but very obscure and mostly unused ones), this doesn’t carry any meaning in Chinese, and I’m 99% sure it’s not Japanese or Korean either. Likely an encoding error?

Comment: I was also advised that there wasn't a direct translation for the characters.

Comment: What anti-malware apps are you using? Have you tried scanning from a boot rescue device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following rootkit detection software:

Malwarebytes

- Found Norassie adware

McAfee Stinger

TrendMicro RootKit Buster

BitDefender BootKit Remover

None found any evidence of a rootkit on this machine.

I booted through an ubuntu live cd and used [dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker.git) to unlock the drive with the recovery key. I ran clamav against the drive:

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 6548066
Engine version: 0.99.4
Scanned directories: 200125
Scanned files: 1481323
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 206973.09 MB
Data read: 346712.86 MB (ratio 0.60:1)
Time: 28746.338 sec (479 m 6 s)
```

At that point I wiped the drive.  It may have been related to Norassie, but I don't have a positive confirmation that it is the cause of the file move.

Answer (score 1):

To answer directly:

Yes, I have seen this from malware installing. I've also seen it from driver discs where the driver was installed with a Chinese language installer.   Windows Defender tends to ignore anything that gets its hands into TrustedInstaller, so you should look into additional malware protection.

BTW it looks like that translates as "Zhuo Yu", who was a military general and strategist from the Han dynasty in China. Considering both the political and cybersecurity climates right now, as someone who speaks English as a primary language, I would be deeply concerned to find Chinese military references moving things around in my computer.   Backup your stuff, run a [boot-time virus scanner](https://www.lifewire.com/free-bootable-antivirus-tools-2625785), and be prepared for a stressful evening.

Comment: The general is Zhou Yu,  not Zhuo Yu. Also goggle doesn't give any useful result for searching the Chinese version. I'd more suspect corruption here than malware.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that this gibberish means Zhuo Yu? That person’s name is written 周瑜... I assure you this is not Chinese (not contemporary Mandarin nor Classical Chinese). This is as much Chinese as “Pcxlfgcso34x9w” is English.

Comment: It's all greek to me...

Comment: What was the malware that caused a similar issue?

Comment: I just passed it trough Google Translate, which isn't super helpful but gave me the rough idea of what someone might have meant when putting it together. It's as likely just a random string.  Looking at the full translation it still came out largely garbage but I can see where Google Translate was trying to go with it.  It's still enough to raise a brow. 
The malware that caused a similar issue was a browser plugin a friend of mine picked up that started interfering with his mouse drivers and, on further investigation, installed a keylogger that was restored by rootkit if you removed it.